# If I rent an apartment and work in one state, can I keep my "permanent" residency in another?

Tags: united-states, residency

I am renting a condo and working in Georgia, but my permanent residence is in NJ at my parents house. Do I have to change my address, license info?

(I have a 1 year lease in Georgia. I have a job in Georgia. I plan to come back to NJ at end of year.)

Comment: Change them for what or who?

Comment: If I am working in Georgia, do I have to change my license info from NJ to Ga or can I keep it as a NJ residency?

Answer (score 1):

Under [Georgia law](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2010/title-40/chapter-5/article-1/40-5-1/), person is a "resident" and must get a Georgia license if he

> has a permanent home or abode in Georgia to which, whenever such
> person is absent, he or she has the intention of returning.

However it also says that

> For the purposes of this chapter, there is a rebuttable presumption
> that the following person is a resident.
>
> (A) Any person who accepts employment or engages in any trade,
> profession, or occupation in Georgia or enters his or her children to
> be educated in the private or public schools of Georgia within ten
> days after the commencement of such employment or education; or
>
> (B) Any person who, except for infrequent, brief absences, has been
> present in the state for 30 or more days provided, however, that no person shall be
> considered a resident for purposes of this chapter unless such person
> is either a United States citizen or an alien with legal authorization
> from the U.S. Immigration and Naturalization Service

By being in the state for more than 30 days and accepting employment in Georgia, the law can now presume that you are a resident. You can rebut that presumption with counter-evidence, that is, doing various things that establish residence in NJ including maintaining  / renewing your driver's licence in NJ, paying NJ state income tax, using your permanent NJ address for your federal income taxes,
voting in NJ (and definitely not voting in GA).